# How does AuthenticationManager implementation gets instantiated in SpringBoot App

Tags: spring-boot

Including spring security starter dependency makes AuthenticationManager available in a spring boot application. I can simply Autowire the AuthenticationManager. How does SpringBoot understand to automatically instantiate the bean for AuthenticationManager though it is in a very different jar file ?

for e.g.

I can simply write

@Autowire
AuthenticationManager authManager;

in my SpringBoot App after including the dependency. How does spring know that it is supposed to instantiate which class and how ?

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration` imports the configuration class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration`, which then provides the bean for the `AuthenticationManager` (it will use a builder to build the authentication manager according to the configuration which is provided).